# Drupal used as a project management tool

Tags: 7

I have been working with drupal for the past 2 years and I'm well aware of its power and extensibility.

I have been thinking for a long time, but has anyone been successful been using drupal as a project management tool.

What modules should be used for making drupal a  project management tool.

*Please keep in mind, we are not looking at some very advanced features, just basic set of features, to get you started.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Open Atrium](http://openatrium.com) is ready drupal system for you (it's free of course). At least, you can investigate modules and theme used there (.\profiles\openatrium folder)...

Comment: Open Atrium would be you best place to start. Alternatively you can build your own using [Og](http://drupal.org/project/og), [Spaces](http://drupal.org/project/spaces), [Features](http://drupal.org/project/spaces).

Comment: This is one too cool. I wonder why I never came across this.

Comment: We're using OpenAtrium alongside with time_tracker module for about six months, and that's workin' well.

Answer (score 5):

Everyone **over designs** project management systems. They end up not being used, or used marginally with only the minimal features. Plus they waste tons of time simply by being confusing. Although I've not used Open Atrium, I've looked into others and found them lacking. Seriously, terribly lacking.

I've had **great** success with the following zero-budget solution:

1) Use the Node Comments module to promote comments to full nodes.

2) Use CCK to make your comment Content Type contain additional fields, such as "start time", "end time", "time worked", "supported by [team members]" and so on.

3) Each "Project" is simply a Page with the project description. Each comment is someone's contribution to the project, with any tracking fields you cared to add to the comment Content Type.

4) Additional "reporting" logic in a custom module that looks at these "time record" comments and generates useful aggregate summaries.

Butt simple.

Total time to get system working: 1 day.

Total time to get company using system: same fricking day!

Feeling of control over their environment by client company: total.

Answer (score 4):

For Drupal 6, there exists the [Project](http://drupal.org/project/project) module can be extended for providing [Bug Tracking](http://drupal.org/project/project_issue) as well.

Answer (score 3):

Things are moving forward in the Drupal community and now there is a complete distribution for project management called ERPAL. See http://erpal.info for more details. ERPAL has full functionality for project management, with invoicing and expense tracking, gantt charts, timetracking, requirements management an much more.

Answer (score 2):

The list of modules for Drupal 7 that are in the category of project management are visible in [this page](http://drupal.org/project/modules?filters=tid%3A19984%20drupal_core%3A103%20bs_project_sandbox%3A0&solrsort=sis_project_release_usage%20desc); both the [Project](http://drupal.org/project/project) module, and the [Case Tracker](http://drupal.org/project/casetracker) module are absent in the list.

If you need to use a module that has been already ported to Drupal 7, then I would suggest you to use one of the modules listed in that page.
If you can wait, then I would suggest to wait until Case Tracker will be ported to Drupal 7; between Case Tracker and Project, Case Tracker is probably the module that will first have a Drupal 7 version.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Storm](http://drupal.org/project/storm) and its associated modules. It can also be used with Open Atrium.

Comment: I found Storm to be great in principle but in practice required an inordinate amount of time to create a work flow and was generally impossible to explain to non-technical staff members how to use.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this page http://groups.drupal.org/node/17948 for a comparison of Project Management / Ticket Tracking Systems

Answer (score 0):

Just to note for completeness, the [Storm module](http://drupal.org/project/storm), which was mentioned in one of the comments has now changed its name to [Project Management](http://drupal.org/project/pm). The name change is active for the Drupal 7 version onwards.